# Is there a benefit to write a function as asynchronous when it is not needed?

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

It is written that:

> Use async code but avoid blocking calls

> Asynchronous programming is a recommended best practice, especially when blocking I/O operations are involved.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#use-async-code-but-avoid-blocking-calls

I have functions which do not contain "await" lines. Is there a benefit to write these functions as async?

Comment: Are "blocking I/O operations involved" ? They should've omitted the _especially_

Comment: Using an async function is like branching out from your synchronous code into a new timeline which you can never merge with the synchronous one. If you need the result of the function in your synchronous code you don't do such things.

Comment: Personally, I don't see any benefit. But using async for the synchronous function will probably confuse the reader.

Comment: Coffee is there in the table doesn't mean you should drink every time you see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have functions which do not contain "await" lines. Is there a
> benefit to write these functions as async?

If the logic of your function is not complicated, then you can use sync function and it is no problem.

As the document says, if you do something like upload or download files, then use async function is a better way. You can put the IO operations in a async method, and call them in the async azure function. This will improve efficiency(This is because Non-IO operations will run together with IO operations).

If you didn't do some operations that take times such as IO operations, then it is no need to use async. Generate thread need to consume memory resources, if you use async in no need places, then this will be a waste.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide this advice to Microsoft (click `Submit and view feedback for -> This Page`, at bottom of [that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#use-async-code-but-avoid-blocking-calls)). They'll tell you why that page is right and this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation you quoted contains some hints on why it's a good idea.

> ### Use async code but avoid blocking calls
>
> Asynchronous programming is a recommended best practice, especially
> when blocking I/O operations are involved.
>
> In C#, always avoid referencing the Result property or calling Wait
> method on a Task instance. This approach **can lead to thread**
> **exhaustion.**
>
> Tip
>
> If you plan to use the HTTP or WebHook bindings, plan to **avoid port**
> **exhaustion** that can be caused by improper instantiation of HttpClient.
> For more information, see How to manage connections in Azure
> Functions.

---

When you have blocking calls they occupy some resources like threads/ports. Which could be shared by various functions.

E.g. Say

- your implementation depends on a 3rd party service that can process 1000s of requests in parallel.
- your [worker process count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_process_count) is 4

Then:

1. If all 4 of them trigger some external job and wait till it's complete, then you'll be able to run only 4 of them in parallel. If your user wanted ability to run 1000 jobs in parallel, you'll have to scale to (and pay for) 250 instances of your app.
2. If each function did following:

   - trigger each job asynchronously and note job-id
   - check job-status in a loop for every job-id

   Then a single app functions would be able to handle 1000s of requests in parallel.

[image]

---

> I have functions which do not contain "await" lines. Is there a benefit to write these functions as async?

It's still good to be async, unless you're sure you've considered all future requirements.